# Using react multiSelect, how can i choose which item is highlighted

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am using https://react-select.com/home in order to show a list of items. Due to other factors i am currently using a multi select even though we always only select ONE item. Default behaviour seems to be to highlight the first item on the list. Is there a way to highlight a specific item on opening of the dropdown?

With a single select its no problem. Orange is selected, orange is highlighted on open dropdown:

[image]

Basically what i want is if a user opens the dropdown AND an item is selected, for the item to be highlighted in blue. As you can see in the following picture, currently, the FIRST item in the list is highlighted.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Lets guess you've options like this

```
const options = [
    { value: 'opt1', label: 'Option 1' },
    { value: 'opt2', label: 'Option 2' },
    { value: 'opt3', label: 'Option 3' },
  ];
```

then you can get the selection by `selectedOptions` this.

```
const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = useState([]);

 const handleSelectChange = (selected) => {
    setSelectedOptions([selectedOptions,...selected]);
  };
```

Comment: Hi there and thanks for answering. Maybe i phrased the question poorly. Let me redo it.